# Return const ref from a unique_ptr

Tags: c++11, c++14

```
class A {};

class B{
    unique_ptr<A> upA;

public:
    B() : upA(make_unique<A>()) {}

    const A* get() const{
        return upA.get();
    }
};
```

How do you return a const reference instead of a const ptr?

Comment: If you have a pointer, do you know how to get the value or object it points to? You *do* know about the dereference operator?

Comment: Yes, I know how to use pointers.  I'm  not sure in the case of unique_ptr how to mod the get function to return ref.

Comment: Well then you change the return type to be a reference, and you dereference the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unary `operator*` - the deference operator:

```
const A& get_ref() const{
    return *upA;
}
```

Comment: Ahh.  Thank you.